# Flutter: set Icon using if conditions

Tags: flutter, if-statement

[image]I'm new in Flutter journey.
I can use use ternary operator to set icon for 2 cases but I need to set Icon for multiple conditions. So, I need to use if or case statement. How can I do that.

I'm adding code as well as screen shoot. Kindly help.

**Code**

```
inputDecoration(title){
  return InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon:
      if(title == 'title'){
    Icon(Icons.title_outlined)
    }
     if(title == 'description'){
    Icon(Icons.description),
      },

    //prefixIcon: title =='title' ? const Icon(Icons.title_outlined) : const Icon(Icons.description),

    prefixIconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if(states.contains(MaterialState.focused)){
        return Colors.green;
      }if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)){
        return Colors.red;
      }
      return Colors.grey;
    }),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
      gapPadding: 15,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3))
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ternary operators or a switch statement.

```
InputDecoration(
            prefixIcon: Icon(
              title == 'title' ? Icons.title_outlined : Icons.description,
            ),
          ),
```

Dart 3 switch expression:

```
  Icon buildPrefix(String title) {
    return switch (title) {
      'description' => const Icon(Icons.description),
      'title' => const Icon(Icons.title_outlined),
      _ => const Icon(Icons.error)
    };
  }

...

 InputDecoration(prefixIcon: buildPrefix(title)),
```

Comment: by the way, it's not necessary to make a separate function to use the switch expression. You could write `InputDecoration(prefixIcon: switch(title) { ...` directly

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that the syntax is acceptable if you were doing an if condition using `if(){}` inside the constuctor, instead you could set this logic before the build.

Example:

```
inputDecoration(title) {
  Widget prefixIcon;
  
  if (title == 'title') {
    prefixIcon = Icon(Icons.title_outlined);
  } else if (title == 'description') {
    prefixIcon = Icon(Icons.description);
  }
  
  return InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: prefixIcon,
    prefixIconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
        return Colors.green;
      } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
        return Colors.red;
      }
      return Colors.grey;
    }),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
      gapPadding: 15,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3))
    )
  );
}
```

or, you could use the ternary operator

```
inputDecoration(title) {
  return InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: title == 'title'
        ? Icon(Icons.title_outlined)
        : (title == 'description' ? Icon(Icons.description) : null),
    prefixIconColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused)) {
        return Colors.green;
      } else if (states.contains(MaterialState.error)) {
        return Colors.red;
      }
      return Colors.grey;
    }),
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
        gapPadding: 15,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3))),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your first code is working nicely. Only need to add a "?" after Widget?. Except that everything works fine. Thanks again.